# How do I loop through multiple tidyverse steps replacing only part of the names of the tables I create along the way?

Tags: r

I want to create a loop which can read in a csv file and perform a series of manipulations creating a summary table which can be compared to a separate summary table. This is for checking the accuracy of the csv outputs. I would like to be able to run through the below steps, replacing E39000018 with the following list of codes one after the other.

E39000026
E39000032
E39000033 
E39000037
E39000040
E39000041
E39000042
E39000043
E39000044
E39000045
E39000046
E39000047

```
library(tidyverse)

T3s <- read.csv("filepath")

'data.frame':   19 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ X        : chr  "Attended" "DNA" "Unknown status"
 $ E39000018: int  2673969 197802 133295
 $ E39000026: int  889621 56906 51781
 $ E39000032: int  1416682 68387 86489
 $ E39000033: int  1593500 107436 84169
 $ E39000037: int  846331 61056 45464
 $ E39000040: int  584536 35720 30146
 $ E39000041: int  1510392 68314 69748
 $ E39000042: int  1484225 64615 80516
 $ E39000043: int  1014140 47329 58536
 $ E39000044: int  1379615 73694 86834
 $ E39000045: int  1060489 49524 73779
 $ E39000046: int  2479127 111282 157571
 $ E39000047: int  1292539 70509 81745
 $ E39000048: int  2282007 115001 155047 

E39000018_csv <- read.csv("filepath")

'data.frame':   54652 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ CCG_CODE                  : chr  "07L" "07L" "07L" "07L"
 $ CCG_ONS_CODE              : chr  "E38000004" "E38000004" "E38000004" "E38000004"
 $ CCG_NAME                  : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
 $ STP_CODE                  : chr  "E54000029" "E54000029" "E54000029" "E54000029"
 $ STPNM                     : chr  "C" "D" "E" "F"
 $ REGIONAL_LO_ONS_CODE      : chr  "E39000018" "E39000018" "E39000018" "E39000018"
 $ REGIONAL_LO_NAME          : chr  "A" "A" "B" "B"
 $ REGION_ONS_CODE           : chr  "E40000003" "E40000003" "E40000003" "E40000003"
 $ REGION_NAME               : chr  "A" "A" "B" "B"
 $ Appointment_Month         : chr  "NOV2017" "NOV2017" "NOV2017" "NOV2017"
 $ APPT_STATUS               : chr  "Attended" "Attended" "Attended" "Attended"
 $ HCP_TYPE                  : chr  "HCP Type Not Provided" "HCP Type Not Provided" "HCP Type Not Provided" "HCP Type Not Provided"
 $ APPT_MODE                 : chr  "Face-to-Face" "Face-to-Face" "Face-to-Face" "Face-to-Face"
 $ TIME_BETWEEN_BOOK_AND_APPT: chr  "1 Day" "15  to 21 Days" "2 to 7 Days"
 $ COUNT_OF_APPOINTMENTS     : int  2904 2320 12142 1109

E39000018_csv <- filter(E39000018_csv, Appointment_Month == "NOV17")
E39000018_STATUS <- E39000018_csv %>%
  group_by(APPT_STATUS) %>%
  summarise(appointments = sum(COUNT_OF_APPOINTMENTS))%>%
  rename(X=APPT_STATUS)
E39000018_STATUS[3,1]="Unknown status"
E39000018_HCP <- E39000018_csv %>%
  group_by(HCP_TYPE) %>%
  summarise(appointments = sum(COUNT_OF_APPOINTMENTS)) %>%
  rename(X=HCP_TYPE)
E39000018_HCP[3,1]="Unknown HCP"
E39000018_MODE <- E39000018_csv %>%
  group_by(APPT_MODE) %>%
  summarise(appointments = sum(COUNT_OF_APPOINTMENTS)) %>%
  rename(X=APPT_MODE)
E39000018_MODE[4,1]="Unknown mode"
E39000018_TIME <- E39000018_csv %>%
  group_by(TIME_BETWEEN_BOOK_AND_APPT) %>%
  summarise(appointments = sum(COUNT_OF_APPOINTMENTS)) %>%
  rename(X=TIME_BETWEEN_BOOK_AND_APPT)
E39000018 <- rbind(E39000018_STATUS, E39000018_HCP, E39000018_MODE, E39000018_TIME)
E39000018_CHECK <- select(T3s, X, E39000018)
E39000018_CHECK <- left_join(E39000018, E39000018_CHECK, by = "X")
E39000018_CHECK <- E39000018_CHECK %>%
  mutate(Check = ifelse(E39000018_CHECK$appointments==E39000018_CHECK$E39000018, "PASS", "FAIL")) %>%
  rename(T3s=E39000018) %>%
  rename(csv=appointments) %>%
  mutate(subregion="E39000018")
```

Result should be a series of CHECK tables joined together using rbind.

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: This question is not reproducible so it will be hard for anyone to give very specific answers. In general, I would suggest putting most/all of the steps into a function, and then using `purrr::map` to apply that to each file. See here for an example: https://serialmentor.com/blog/2016/6/13/reading-and-combining-many-tidy-data-files-in-R

Comment: This would be the table for E39000018 and there would be one like this for each code joined together using rbind to make a single table. ~~~Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 19 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X        : chr  "Attended" "DNA" "Unknown status" "HCP Type Not Provided" ...
 $ csv      : int  2790249 230375 93783 3114407 NA NA 2653408 14215 386138 50067 ...
 $ T3s      : int  2673969 197802 133295 NA NA 32202 2513581 16422 443232 21565 ...
 $ Check    : chr  "FAIL" "FAIL" "FAIL" NA ...
 $ subregion: chr  "E39000018" "E39000018" "E39000018" "E39000018" ~~~

Comment: Okay, I'll give purrr::map a try. Thanks. Will let you know.

Comment: @JEmily It is not clear what you wanted given that there is no data or expected ouputt